# count the appearance of the first digits in sales id in a database

Tags: mysql, count

i have a database with sales of items and it's price and quantity and i can calculate the revenue using these. the question is "Show the distribution of the numbers of the sales. We should take the first digit of the revenue, and we should count the appearance of the first digits as below. Order the result set by the distribution from the most to the lowest, as below"

this is supposed to be the expected result. can anyone please help
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `LEFT()` function to get the first digit. Then use a grouped count to get the distribution.

```
SELECT LEFT(revenue, 1) AS FirstDigit, COUNT(*) AS Distribution
FROM Sales
GROUP BY FirstDigit
ORDER BY Distribution DESC
```